# Checking Win32 file streams for available input

Tags: winapi

I have a simple tunnel program that needs to simultaneously block on standard input and a socket.  I currently have a program that looks like this (error handling and boiler plate stuff omitted):

```
HANDLE host = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
SOCKET peer = ...; // socket(), connect()...

WSAEVENT gate = WSACreateEvent();
OVERLAPPED xfer;
ZeroMemory(&xfer, sizeof(xfer));
xfer.hEvent = gate;
WSABUF pbuf = ...; // allocate memory, set size.

// start an asynchronous transfer.
WSARecv(peer, &pbuf, 1, 0, &xfer, 0);
while ( running )
{
    // wait until standard input has available data or the event
    // is signaled to inform that socket read operation completed.
    HANDLE handles[2] = { host, gate };
    const DWORD which = WaitForMultipleObjects
        (2, handles, FALSE, INFINITE) - WAIT_OBJECT_0;

    if (which == 0)
    {
        // read stuff from standard input.
        ReadFile(host, ...);
        // process stuff received from host.
        // ...
    }
    if (which == 1)
    {
        // process stuff received from peer.
        // ...
        // start another asynchronous transfer.
        WSARecv(peer, &pbuf, 1, 0, &xfer, 0);
    }
}
```

The program works like a charm, I can transfer stuff through this tunnel program without a hitch.  The thing is that it has a subtle bug.

If I start this program in interactive mode from `cmd.exe` and standard input is attached to the keyboard, pressing a key that does not produce input (e.g. the `Ctrl` key) makes this program block and ignore data received on the socket.  I managed to realize that this is because pressing *any* key signals the standard input handle and `WaitForMultipleObjects()` returns.  As expected, control enters the `if (which == 0)` block and the call to `ReadFile()` blocks because there is no input available.

Is there a means to detect how much input is available on a Win32 stream?  If so, I could use this to check if any input is available before calling `ReadFile()` to avoid blocking.

I know of a few solutions for specific types of streams (notably `ClearCommError()` for serial ports and `ioctlsocket(socket,FIONBIO,&count)` for sockets), but none that I know of works with the `CONIN$` stream.

Answer (score 2):

Use overlapped I/O.  Then test the event attached to the I/O operation, instead of the handle.

For `CONIN$` specifically, you might also look at the Console Input APIs, such as [`PeekConsoleInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684344.aspx) and [`GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683207.aspx)

But I really recommend using OVERLAPPED (background) reads wherever possible and not trying to treat `WaitForMultipleObjects` like `select`.

Since the console can't be overlapped in overlapped mode, your simplest options are to wait on the console handle and use `ReadConsoleInput` (then you have to process control sequences manually), or spawn a dedicated worker thread for synchronous `ReadFile`.  If you choose a worker thread, you may want to then connect a pipe between that worker and the main I/O loop, using overlapped pipe reads.

Another possibility, which I've never tried, would be to wait on the console handle and use `PeekConsoleInput` to find out whether to call `ReadFile` or `ReadConsoleInput`.  That way you should be able to get non-blocking along with the cooked terminal processing.  OTOH, passing control sequences to `ReadConsoleInput` might inhibit the buffer-manipulation actions they were supposed to take.

---

If the two streams are processed independently, or nearly so, it may make more sense to start a thread for each one.  Then you can use a blocking read from standard input.

Comment: You should also take a look at this, which seems to be a good way to do it: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/285863-non-blocking-stdin-read-on-win32/

Comment: @Polynomial: I'd stay away from any and all of the code posted on that discussion.

Comment: Sure, it's not the best code, but the `ReadConsole` / `_kbhit()` trick is quite nice.

Comment: Ah man, how did I *not* think of this.  I'm already using the exact same feature for the socket...  I'll try this out at once and let you know how it works.

Comment: Got sample code working.  It seems to work for input files, but not for the standard input (not previously opened for overlapped I/O) or the `CONIN$` device (seemingly can't be opened for overlapped I/O at all).

Comment: Indeed, the "Consoles" section in the [documentation for `CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) says that `dwFlagsAndAttributes` is ignored when opening console objects.

Comment: @AndréCaron: One simple workaround is to have another thread that just copies data from CONIN$ to a pipe.  The main thread can use overlapped I/O with the pipe.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Another thing to note is that, as you noted in your question, not all kinds of input will cause `ReadFile` to return.  But any time the console object is signaled, `ReadConsoleInput` will return immediately.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't need to add a pipe.  All I/O and tunnel state is independant for reading and writing.  I'll just add a second thread that uses the blocking `ReadFile()` call on the standard input and it'll clean up the issue.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Ah well, if the two sources don't interact (much), then a separate thread is by far the easiest approach.

Comment: Can you update your answer with information in the comments that answer the question?  If so, I'll accept it.

Comment: Sorry, it's been quite a while.  I ended up using the thread-based solutuion suggested in your comments.  If you update your answer to include the thread-based approach, I'll accept that.