# Possible to stop cin from waiting input?

Tags: c++, windows, iostream, blocking, boost-thread

In a graphical application I execute debug commands using the console input. When the console is created a new thread is also created to gather the user commands that handles all that input, the graphical application continues running parallel. I use boost::thread library.

It works good so far, however I haven't found a nice solution to stop the execution of this thread. The thread is always waiting for a user input:

```
 while(appRunning)
 {
     std::cin>>theUserCommand;
     // ...do stuff
 }
```

Then when the graphical application ends, it will stop all console functions, in which I include the thread:

```
 appRunning = false;
 // do some more related clean up
 myListeningThread->join();
```

As you can see the std::cin will be waiting for user input, after the join has being called.
One of the solutions I tried is to create events "synthetizing keystrokes", the std::cin will get whatever value you send with an ENTER, the thread will end nicely, this solutions is horrible and I don't want to keep it.
Besides, it did work in one of the environments the tool is executed, but fails when I tried using it along with a UI API. Could you guys guide me how can I fix this in a correct way? Can't really say for sure if in the C++ documentation there is a function to stop std::cin waiting for user input, and just and continue the program execution, is it even possible?

EDIT: Fine I find that keybd_event  is a bit misleading for some environments, explicitly specifying the input handler with the WriteConsoleInput works good.

Comment: There are several possibilities, but all of them are OS-dependent.  What operating system is this program for?

Comment: Win/VStudio9.0, I used the keybd_event for the solution I mentioned, there is no problem if it will be OS-dependent. how would you recommend me to fix it?

Comment: BTW, SetConsoleCtrlHandler doesn't really work for me, this will end the application process skipping all the clean up for the application to end.

Comment: @curiousguy: that's definitely a UNIX-only solution and will never work on Windows.  There is not `close(int);` function and `0` is not the standard input handle.

Comment: There is `close(int)`, it's just called `_close` for no good reason whatsoever (yes, I've had to port POSIX-API code to Windows, why do you ask?) But I wouldn't expect that to do anything constructive. The equivalent in terms of actual system calls would be `CloseHandle(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)))` and ... I have no idea what that would do to a different thread reading from the same handle.  Try it and tell us!

Comment: Hmm, if you can require Vista or later, [CancelSynchronousIo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363794%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be very helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

I am not much of a Windows programmer, I know a whole lot more about Unix.  And I am totally unfamiliar with `boost::thread`.  That said, based on the advice at the bottom of [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), here is my recommendation:

- Create an [event object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before you create the console-reading thread.
- When you want to shut down, call [`SetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the event object immediately before calling the thread's `->join` method.
- Change the main loop in your console-reading thread to block in [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) rather than `istream::operator>>`, something like this:

  ```
  for (;;) {
      HANDLE h[2];
      h[0] = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
      h[1] = that_event_object_I_mentioned;
      DWORD which = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, h, FALSE, INFINITE);

      if (which == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
          processConsoleCommand();
      else if (which == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1)
          break;
      else
          abort();
  }
  ```
- This thread must take care not to do any blocking operation other than the `WaitForMultipleObjects` call.  Per the discussion in the comments below, that means `processConsoleCommand` can't use `cin` at all.  You will need to use the [low-level console input functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead, notably `GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents` and `ReadConsoleInput`, to ensure that you do not block; you will need to accumulate characters across many calls to `processConsoleCommand` until you read a carriage return; and you will also need to do your own echoing.

Comment: Note that blocking on the standard input using `WaitForMultipleObjects()` to avoid a blocking read is fundamentally unreliable.  If the standard input is the keyboard (`CONIN$` device), then pressing any key (even those, such as `CTRL`, that produce no input) will unblock the wait only to block on the next input operation indefinitely, resulting in the thread ignoring the event's state.  Check out a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347642/checking-win32-file-streams-for-available-input) for more details.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if this thread winds up spinning through `WaitForMultipleObjects` when the user is typing, as long as it goes properly idle when the user *isn't* typing.  I would like to think that there's some equivalent of [`FIONREAD`](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/ioctl.2.html) that can be used to ensure that `ReadFile` will not block, but Windows has surprised me with the absence of similar facilities before.  If something like this can't be made to work, I think I'd be looking at implementing my own console window with the GUI APIs.

Comment: ... The discussion in that related question doesn't really help; the recommendation seems to be "use a dedicated thread to read from the console" and here we are discussing how to implement precisely such a thread.

Comment: That's the thing.  I had a problem with exactly this code where pressing `CTRL+TAB` or `ALT+TAB` would unblock from the wait and then the next operation on `std::cin` would block because there was no real input in the console's buffer.  And you are not implementing a dedicated loop for the standard input since you are waiting on both the standard input *and* and event.

Comment: It looks to me like that problem can be worked around by using the low-level Win32 console input functions instead of `cin`.  More work, yeah.  And how _else_ are you to make your dedicated console-reading thread exit, short of `TerminateThread`, which is a bad idea for obvious reasons?  That is, after all, the question that was originally asked.

Comment: I'm not aware of all the capabilities of the console functions, but they won't work as expected if the standard input is redirected to a file or a pipe.  I'm afraid there is no way to implement a general solution to the problem OP asked, at least not on Windows.  The way I "solved" it for my related question is to have a blocking call on the standard input read operation in the main thread and have the I/O on my other stream (a socket) in a background thread.  The two threads join at the end of main and it works.  But that was clean for my problem since I always want to exhaust both streams.

Comment: This looks an possible solution, let me try this I will let you know how it behaves..