# How to stop waiting for user input in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a simple code as below.

```
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
```

If the user only inputs one number, the program will hang there waiting for another input. How do I stop the situation automatically and let the user to enter two numbers again if there is no input for a time, like 30 seconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to stop cin from waiting input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569027/possible-to-stop-cin-from-waiting-input)

Comment: The solution depends on the platform.  What platform, OS and IDE/Compiler are you using?

Comment: I run it on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy / universal way to do so. There are separate methods for Linux (alarm, signal handlers, followed by manual stream flushing and resetting) and Windows (not sure -- implement your own readline using raw keyboard input?), but they are all quite complicated and hard to get right.