# Windows C++ - closing thread with CloseHandle

Tags: c++, windows

I have created a thread by the "CreateThread" function.

in this thread, I have a 'while(true)' loop (that reads input).

for now, when I want to close the thread, I use the 'CloseHandle' function.

Is this the right thing to do? Or I should exit the 'while(true)' loop and then use the 'CloseHandle' function?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

CloseHandle() does not destroy, terminate or supspend the thread, it only destroys the handle itself (so then you don't have a handle to kill the thread or wait on it). The thread continues to work normally (I have utilised this in numerous cases), and the only way to stop it is either exit the thread function (ThreadProc()), or kill it.

Comment: Note: To remove the thread object, handle must be closed after use.  [Quoted From msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle). 
> Closing a thread handle does not terminate the associated thread or remove the thread object. Closing a process handle does not terminate the associated process or remove the process object. To remove a thread object, you must terminate the thread, then close all handles to the thread.

Answer (score 6):

Generally this (calling TerminateThread) is a bad thing to do because a thread may allocate some resources (i.e., file descriptors) which will be unavailable until the whole process terminate. Even more, the CloseHandle does not stop the thread.

If you have some lengthy operation inside your thread, then at least use the

```
while(!ShouldExit)
{
     DoOneMoreIteration();
}
```

cycle. This way you can terminate the thread by setting ShouldExit to 1 (or 'true', if it is C++ and bool variable) and the call WaitForSingleObject on this thread's handle to ensure it has finished.

For eran's comment: The ShouldExit must be declared as 'volatile'.

If you're waiting for some input (a console I suppose), then you might use the non-blocking ("overlapped") I/O with standard input.

E.g., see this question: [Checking Win32 file streams for available input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347642/checking-win32-file-streams-for-available-input)

It would be something like

```
HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

while(!ShouldExit) {
   if(WaitForSingleObject(h, FALSE, SomeTimeoutValue) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
   {
      ... use std::cin - it has some input and won't block
   }
}
```

To make things better (avoid CPU overburn) use WaitForMultipleObjects and break outside the loop on some external event.

```
/// Global var
HANDLE SomeGlobalEvent;

/// ThreadProc():
HANDLE h[2];
h[0] = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
h[1] = SomeGlobalEvent;

while(true) {
   DWORD which = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, h, FALSE, SomeTimeoutValue);
   if(which == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
   {
      ... use std::cin - it has some input and won't block
   } else
   if(which == WAIT_OBJECT_1)
   {
      // got the termination event
      break;
   }
}


/// "Main" thread:

SomeGlobalEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);

HANDLE hThread = _beginthread(ThreadProc, 4096, NULL);

 ....
 /// send termination signal
 SetEvent(SomeGlobalEvent);

 /// Wait for thread completion
 WaitForSingleObject(hThread);
```

Comment: @kakush, if you go for the `ShouldExit`, make sure you declare it as `volatile`. Otherwise, it might not do the trick.

Comment: @eran: The `volatile` trick works *only* for Visual C++ compilers. It may not work on other compilers.

Comment: "Other" - you mean gcc? It will.

Comment: @eran: 'volatile' works on embedded IAR's C compiler and on GCC also. So it's pretty much "everywhere"

Comment: @ViktorLatypov, it wasn't me who claimed volatile works only on VC... But many questions have been asked on this topic, and diving into the details is beyond the scope of this question anyway.

Comment: -1 for a couple of reasons. `volatile` cannot be used to make code thread-safe. It is not a substitute for proper locking mechanisms (e.g. mutexes). But the main reason for the downvote is that it does not answer the question, which is "Is it safe to close the thread handle returned by CreateProcess?"

Answer (score 3):

Best thing is to read the docs carefully. Win32 API is well documented.

from [MSDN on CreateThread in the Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885186.aspx) it says

> Thread execution begins at the function specified by the lpStartAddr
>   parameter. If this function returns, the DWORD return value is used to
>   terminate the thread in an implicit call to the ExitThread function.
>   Use the GetExitCodeThread function to get the thread's return value.

Following on from that, you should let the thread entry function do its job and finish. I.e. exit the loop which would return the thread entry function.