# Closing threads methods

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

What is the difference between

```
ExitThread(exitcode);
```

and

```
CloseHandle(threadHandle);
```

?

It seems that they do the same thing, but they must have a difference.

Comment: Yes. That's kinda obvious.

Comment: CloseHandle does not kill the thread which handle is closed. Rather, it "detaches" the thread. Also, it does not create resource leaks; rather opposite, its purpose is to avoid resource leak for the thread object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions do very different things. `ExitThread` immediately ends the calling thread. `CloseHandle` just destroys a handle, thus removing a reference to a thread object. It has no affect on the thread which handle is closed; the thread will continue its normal execution. Typically, a thread handle is closed after the thread has finished (e.g. after waiting for its completion with `WaitForSingleObject`). But sometimes, a handle is closed for the thread that is still running; it's often referred as detaching a thread. This needs to be done if the application "forgets" the thread and will not wait for its completion; handles to such a thread should be closed to let the kernel automatically destroy associated resources when the thread completes.

Also see answers to a similar question: [Windows C++ - closing thread with CloseHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226072/windows-c-closing-thread-with-closehandle)